# Unable to locate package caffe-cpu

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, caffe

I am trying to install caffe, but ran into the following error

```
sudo apt-get install caffe-cpu
[sudo] password for : 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package caffe-cpu
```

This is my version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I tried following the instructions here https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Installing-Caffe-CPU-Only/

Got

```
CXX src/caffe/test/test_hdf5_output_layer.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/test/test_hdf5_output_layer.cpp:8:0:
./include/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.hpp:4:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:581: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_hdf5_output_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_hdf5_output_layer.o] Error 1
```

This is what I have

```
  ThinkPad-T520:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls -al | grep libhdf5_serial
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        53 Jul 19 10:03 libhdf5_hl.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root  19953086 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial.a
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root   1659560 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.a
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        32 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10.0.2
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        32 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10.0.2
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root    238408 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.10.0.2
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root    878832 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_hl.a
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root    515320 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.a
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        34 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10.0.2
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        34 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10.0.2
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root     80520 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.10.0.2
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        27 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_hl.so -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        27 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10 -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root    126232 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root      3859 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial.settings
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        24 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial.so -> libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        24 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial.so.10 -> libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root   2734288 Apr  5  2016 libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        50 Jul 19 10:03 libhdf5.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0
```

After making changes to Makefine.config, getting

```
CXX src/caffe/util/hdf5.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/benchmark.cpp
CXX src/caffe/internal_thread.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:572: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

Comment: That is because it is not in the repositories.  See:  https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Installing-Caffe-CPU-Only/

Comment: Can you please check out my edits above? I am still getting stuck...

Comment: See:  https://gist.github.com/nikitametha/c54e1abecff7ab53896270509da80215 and go down to where it says to resolve the hdf5 errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now getting a different error, please see edit above.

Comment: Go back to the link and make sure that all the required applications are installed.

Comment: Will do, thanks. Btw, how do I check my blas version? Tried

grep OPENBLAS_VERSION /usr/local/include/openblas_config.h 
grep: /usr/local/include/openblas_config.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Now I am getting this error

CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

even though I do have opencv:

sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libopencv-dev is already the newest version (2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1).
python-opencv is already the newest version (2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Try running `sudo ldconfig` on your system to fix any ld errors.  Beyond that, I am out of suggestions.  I have never set this up before and this is why I have not written an answer.  The links were only suggestions to follow.  I wish I was more help.

Comment: No, it's been great, I wouldn't have gotten this far without you, thank you so much! I will try that and report back. Is it not an opencv issue though?

Comment: Thank you so much Terrance, thanks to your advice I was finally able to do it!

Comment: Glad you got it working!  =)

Answer (score 2):

caffe-cpu is in the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 and you can install caffe-cpu with the following command:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install caffe-cpu
```

Results of `apt-cache showpkg caffe-cpu` in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Reverse Depends: 
  caffe-cuda,caffe-cpu
  caffe-cpu:i386,caffe-cpu
  science-machine-learning,caffe-cpu
Dependencies: 
1.0.0-6 - caffe-tools-cpu (5 1.0.0-6) python3-caffe-cpu (5 1.0.0-6) libcaffe-cpu1 (5 1.0.0-6) libopenblas-base (16 (null)) libatlas3-base (16 (null)) libblas.so.3 (0 (null)) caffe-cuda (0 (null)) libcaffe-cpu-dev (5 1.0.0-6) caffe-doc (5 1.0.0-6) caffe-cpu:i386 (32 (null)) 
Provides: 
1.0.0-6 -
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install -s caffe-cpu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  caffe-tools-cpu libboost-python1.65.1 libcaffe-cpu1 libgflags2.2
  libgoogle-glog0v5 libleveldb1v5 liblmdb0 python3-caffe-cpu python3-gflags
  python3-leveldb
Suggested packages:
  libcaffe-cpu-dev caffe-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  caffe-cpu caffe-tools-cpu libboost-python1.65.1 libcaffe-cpu1 libgflags2.2
  libgoogle-glog0v5 libleveldb1v5 liblmdb0 python3-caffe-cpu python3-gflags
  python3-leveldb
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libboost-python1.65.1 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst libgflags2.2 (2.2.1-1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst libgoogle-glog0v5 (0.3.5-1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst libleveldb1v5 (1.20-2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst liblmdb0 (0.9.21-1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst libcaffe-cpu1 (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst caffe-tools-cpu (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst python3-gflags (1.5.1-5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [all])
Inst python3-leveldb (0~svn68-3build3 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst python3-caffe-cpu (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Inst caffe-cpu (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf libboost-python1.65.1 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf libgflags2.2 (2.2.1-1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf libgoogle-glog0v5 (0.3.5-1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf libleveldb1v5 (1.20-2 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf liblmdb0 (0.9.21-1 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf libcaffe-cpu1 (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf caffe-tools-cpu (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf python3-gflags (1.5.1-5 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [all])
Conf python3-leveldb (0~svn68-3build3 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf python3-caffe-cpu (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
Conf caffe-cpu (1.0.0-6 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic [amd64])
```

Comment: so just do sudo apt-get upgrade first, or you've got other suggestions?

Comment: caffe-cpu has got a lot of dependencies that are also only in the default Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

Comment: A friend of mine has 18.04, and got the same error. What's going on?

Comment: Nope, getting the same error on 18.04 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to get up and running is to use conda. This way allows you to have many different caffe environments. First install miniconda, then make an environment

```
conda create -n caffe
```

then

```
conda install caffe
```

OR

```
conda install caffe-gpu
```

Not only does conda solve all the dependencies but it also installs the correct version of cudatoolkit and cudnn. And if you want python 2 you can

```
conda create -n python2Caffe-GPU python=2.7

conda install caffe-gpu=1.0=py27heda4471_3
```

The variable, py27heda4471_3, is the build version and you have many to choose from

```
conda search caffe-gpu
```

gives a list