# E: Unable to locate package caffe-cuda

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, caffe

I tried to install Caffe through the link https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html and I got the error `E: Unable to locate package caffe-cuda`.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=caffe-cuda shows it's in *multiverse* ; do you have multiverse repo. enabled?  *You didn't provide your release; so if you're not a release listed in my search how am I to know unless you tell me*

Comment: What’s your Ubuntu version? What exact command did you use? (You can check your [Bash history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-ran-in-terminal).)

Comment: Ubuntu version is 16.04 and i used make -j8 command

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all details. Provide the commands along with their outputs. The `make` command is definitely not relevant to the output you posted in your question.

Comment: @Merlebius According to the linked tutorial in the question that command the generated the error message was `sudo apt install caffe-cpu` because this tutorial was specific to a later release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 16.04 does not have this package and many of its dependencies in its default repositories.

Comment: @karel Yes, I expected this, too, but I also tried to teach OP how to make a well-explained question. Forgive me if I was too harsh.

Answer (score 1):

According to the link in your question *everything including caffe itself is packaged in 17.04 and higher versions*, but you are currently using Ubuntu 16.04 which does not contain these packages in its default repositories.

caffe-cuda is not available from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. Ubuntu 16.04 can be upgraded directly to Ubuntu 18.04 which is the next LTS release after 16.04. To install caffe-cuda in Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install caffe-cuda
```

For information about installing other caffe packages in Ubuntu 16.04 see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057602/unable-to-locate-package-caffe-cpu/1057603#1057603).