# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS: Unable to locate package caffe-cuda

Tags: apt, package-management

My problem is similar to this one, [E: Unable to locate package caffe-cuda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158644/e-unable-to-locate-package-caffe-cuda), but I will try to give more details.

I used the folowing command to install `caffe-cuda`:

```
sudo apt install caffe-cuda
```

and got the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package caffe-cuda
```

So I tried `apt-cache search caffe` and got this:

```
caffe-cpu - Fast, open framework for Deep Learning (Meta)
caffe-doc - Caffe's doxygen docs and examples
caffe-tools-cpu - Tools for fast, open framework for Deep Learning (CPU_ONLY)
caffeine - prevent the desktop becoming idle in full-screen mode
git-cola - highly caffeinated git GUI
gnome-shell-extension-caffeine - GNOME Shell extension to keep your computer awake
libcaffe-cpu-dev - development files for Caffe (CPU_ONLY)
libcaffe-cpu1 - library of Caffe, deep learning framework (CPU_ONLY)
libcaffeine-java - High performance caching library
libdeepboof-java - Java library for running deep neural networks
python3-caffe-cpu - Python3 interface of Caffe (CPU_ONLY)
python3-theano - CPU/GPU math expression compiler for Python 3
ttf-aenigma - 465 free TrueType fonts by Brian Kent
```

Why is there no `caffe-cuda` here? Can anyone suggest a solution?

Here is my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the original [source](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html) and it seems you can install `caffe` with

```
sudo apt install caffe-cuda
```

or

```
sudo apt install caffe-cpu
```

As per https://packages.ubuntu.com/, it also gives the same information about both packages:

> #### Package caffe-cuda
>
> - [bionic (18.04LTS)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/caffe-cuda) (metapackages): Fast, open framework for Deep Learning (Meta)
>   [**multiverse**]
>   1.0.0-6build1: amd64 ppc64el
>
> #### Package caffe-cpu
>
> - [bionic (18.04LTS)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/caffe-cpu) (metapackages): Fast, open framework for Deep Learning (Meta)
>   [**universe**]
>   1.0.0-6: amd64 arm64 i386 ppc64el s390x
> - [focal (20.04LTS)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/caffe-cpu) (metapackages): Fast, open framework for Deep Learning (Meta)
>   [**universe**]
>   1.0.0+git20180821.99bd997-5build3: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x

So it seems to me that on Ubuntu 20.04 you should use `caffe-cpu`, unless there is some specific reason you want to use `caffe-cuda`.

In that case, you can try to add the repository for Ubuntu 18.04. Just copy the repos you have in your `sources.list` and append them at the end of the file. Then substitute `focal` with `bionic` in these entries.

Or maybe it is better to download the `.deb` file from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/caffe-cuda/download and install it with:

```
dpkg -i <package_name>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ignore my last comment. The reason why you cannot install `caffe-cuda`, is because it doesn’t exist (not in Ubuntu’s official repo anyway).

Comment: But it does exist in Ubuntu 18.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=caffe-cuda. So if I want to install it, then I can only change the system version?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `caffe-cuda` is not supported in Ubuntu 20.04 is hinted at in

```
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6993
```

Basically, `caffe-cuda` depends on cudnn API methods that were dropped in / by cudnn 8.0.  The `caffe-cuda` codebase has basically been left behind ... by NVidia.

It is apparently possible to get `caffe-cuda` to work on Ubuntu 20.04.   However, it is long and complicated procedure. There is a article on how to do it here:

- [How to setup Caffe with CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN (7.6.5) in ubuntu 20.04 complete guide.](https://techboutique-official.medium.com/how-to-setup-caffe-with-cuda-10-1-and-cudnn-7-6-5-in-ubuntu-20-04-complete-guide-7a7f58cf0616)

I noticed that the article *seems* to contradict itself.  At the start it tells you how to download and install cudnn 7.6.5, but towards the end it seems to say that this causes dependency problems.  Read it carefully, and make up your own mind.

---

My recommendation would be to take the easy path and use `caffe-cpu`.  Or look for an alternative to Caffe.