# Ubuntu 21.04 - Install a package (caffe-cuda) from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, 21.04, caffe

I have to install Caffe for a project in my university. I am new to Ubuntu and I am using it since I wasn't able to build Caffe on Windows at all.

I have tried following the original [tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html). If I run `sudo apt install caffe-cuda`, I get the error `Unable to locate package caffe-cuda`. I understand, based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329496/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-unable-to-locate-package-caffe-cuda), that this package is only available in 18.04 repositories. If I understand correctly, there is an easy [way](https://rdr-it.com/en/ubuntu-18-04-add-multiverse-and-universe-repositories/) to get these packages, but unfortunately, after I run `sudo apt update`, a bunch of errors pop up, like

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And if I run `apt-cache search caffe`, `caffe-cuda` is not there.

Right now, the only solution that comes to my mind is manually installing each [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=caffe-cuda) with its dependencies, but since every dependency has a dependency and so on, I was hoping there was an easier way.

I ask to you: am I missing something? What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get 18.04 packages cleanly?

Comment: What you are doing wrong: Not fixing those apt errors first.

Comment: Deb packages are made to work with a specific release of Ubuntu (due to shared dependency versions). It is very unlikely that you will get 18.04 packages to work on 21.04. This is a common mistake that new users coming from Windows make. Either run 18.04 packages on an 18.04 system, or install from source (instead of packages).

Comment: An alternative would be to use `caffe-cpu` instead of `caffe-cuda`, if you do not need the support of the GPU